# The way of running zabbix by docker do not work

Tags: docker, zabbix

I running the 3 containers below for setting up zabbix GUI application.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS       PORTS                                      NAMES
6e3f2d650434   zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   5 hours ago    Up 4 hours   8080/tcp, 8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   zabbix-web-nginx-mysql
5d900c79adc0   zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:latest      "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   5 hours ago    Up 4 hours   0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp                   zabbix-server-mysql
30c8a58f8ea3   mysql:5.7                              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 hours ago   Up 4 hours   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                        mysql-server
```

you see the `zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql`, it has `0.0.0.0:8080 -> 80/tcp`.

but I can not access the `127.0.0.1:8080` from my host.

I checked the 8080 port by nmap, it's opened.

```
$ nmap 127.0.0.1 -p 8080
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-03 15:20 CST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00036s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds
```

but I cannot access it

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

and cannot enter the container:
when I execute docker attach command, it will get stuck:

```
$ docker attach 6e3f2d650434
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this one? just ran into the same issue